# Will upgrading phonegap local database android app lose old data?

Tags: android, cordova, upgrade, local-database

I am developing a phonegap app to store data into local database.

I am about to publish(version 1.0) and upgrade(version 1.1) the app into android market.

But before that I would like to confirm that..

When user installs update, will they lose data entered in version 1.0?

I Googled this, but haven't got any posts confirming this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have used local storage (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage) then the data is saved across upgrades.

If you used the database (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Database) then I believe it  will be saved, however I've never personally tried this.

Comment: Thanks Steve for a prompt reply, I am using the database(http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Database)

Comment: Great...!!! :) Just checked the real scenario. Didn't lose database. Phonegap is awesome. :)

Cheers... :)